# Can a class factory also save the object to a database?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, architecture, programming-practices

How can a factory also save the object in the database?

I want to create an object that consists of other objects.

Pseudocode:

```
firstObject = db.get....;
secondObject = db.get....;
expectedObject = new ExpectedObject(firstObject, secondObject, userId, datetime);
```

This is the task for the factory pattern. But I would also like to save my new object (expectedObject) in the database.

```
db.save(expectedObject);
```

Can I do it in this factory or should it be a separate service?

Comment: I’d do it in a separate service, as you could have many different factories create the result object in different ways. If you save in the factory, other factories would need to save too. That’s pure duplication. Now if you want to change the way you save, you’d have to change every single factory. This is a waste of time, energy and just another way to make mistakes. Oh and it’s also **way** harder to test if you save inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short all classes should have a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), I describe the class to myself and If I need to use a compounding word like **AND** or **ALSO** then it probably has two responsibilities joined by that word. I divide the functionality of the class on that word.  So here divided your requirements into *creation* and *saving*.

A class [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) can be used to create [Data Transfer Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which understand how to save their state to a database.  This is an inversion of responsibility aka the tell don't ask idiom.

Pseudo code would look something like this:

```
DTO customer = Factory.createCustomer();
customer.saveTo(db);
```

Naming classes for objects should generally reflect that single responsibility from the business domain, so `Customer` or `Address`, it is fairly common to postfix the class name with something like DTO. with that so `CustomerDto` or `AddressDto`.

Comment: How to name a saving class? CustomerFactory and? CustomerStorage?

Comment: Can you give an example of how to name this service?

Comment: Not really, you know the domain it will be used in, and it will vary each time you apply the technique. All program names should accurately describe the thing, service, class, variable to maximise the understanding to yourself in X weeks or somebody else coming all totally new.  Ask yourself the question will I/they understand what this is supposed to do?  A good convention is to name it after the business thing it is, not the programming thing it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Comment: I think this answer is correct, but it does overstate the SRP.  In the (unlikely) event that the stakeholder wants the creator of objects to always save them, SRP does not prohibit that design.

Comment: I also disagree with the statement on AND and ALSO. I sometimes put two responsibilities into the same class because separating them while keeping other good pracrices would take 3 times more code and be (felt) 10 times more complex.

Comment: That is a guideline to SRP not a hard and fast rule; responsibilities can be combined but then the responsibility is binding the two parts together.  SRP leads to delegation which produces less code overall and localises the complexity; any specific class/feature is less complex overall.

Comment: @MartinSpamer SRP can help with maintenance and complexity localization but only if used properly. It is a fine line to walk on - too much class specialization (as in, taking the SRP to the extreme) can lead to a terrible horde of anemic classes that do barely anything and just replicate procedural code. Balance is the key - if creating an object and saving it being together in a single class makes sense on your context, by all means, go ahead. If it does more sense to keep it split into two different things, then go that way.

Comment: @marstato: Taking your example as objectively correct observation, then the separation of classes is not the "best practice" choice of the two. Good practice is a judgment call based on the reasonable pros and cons of different approaches. If your separation leads to unreadably complex code, it wouldn't be good practice to separate. However, I do think that the "triple code" argument isn't a solid justification. There is of course _some_ reasonable upper limit on code bloat, but I wouldn't say it applies to `k = 3`.

Comment: @Flater i'm happy to discuss that further in the chat, would probably blow the scope of the comments here.